# SwiftUI: 'some' return types are only available in macOS 10.15.0 or newer - on MacOS Ventura

Tags: swiftui, swift-package-manager

I have some strange error in my SPM.

**Code example:**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {

  var body: some View {
    Text("Stub")
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> 'some' return types are only available in macOS 10.15.0 or newer

But I have `macOS Ventura 13.0.1`, & `XCode 14.1`. What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your deployment target?

Comment: Are you making your own package or importing one? If you are creating one check `swift-tools-version` and `platforms` on your **Package.swift** file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved.

I needed to change simulator from Mac (by Default) to iPhone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks fine. As @Timmy mentioned, there's probably something wrong with the project settings. Try upping the deployment target...

1. Go to your project settings by selecting your project in Project Navigator.

[image]

2. Select your project

[image]

3. And change the deployment target

[image]